# Shouldn't table.undo() clear any cell.isEdited() flag when the undo "undoes" a cell edit?

Tags: tabulator, undo

In Tabulator - when using the history module and - the function undo(): It seems that the cell flag isEdited() doesn't get cleared when the undo undoes a cell edit.

I want to mark all edited cells in a table through CSS, but after I did an undo() on the table I noticed that the edit markings were not removed - even though the cells got "undone" as they should.

To mark edited cells, I use a function that look like this:

```
const setEditedCellsVisibility = () => {
    
    document.querySelectorAll(".tabulator-cell").forEach( element => {
        element.classList.remove('edited');
    })
    
    //(The "Table" is set up elsewhere, but is a normal tabulator table)
    Table.getEditedCells().forEach( cell => { 
        cell.getElement().classList.add('edited')
    })
}
```

Do I need to "manually" clear the flag for cell.isEdited() after each Table.undo() call?